# Full width dropdown with submenu below nav item

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar

I want to display the submenu of the Bootstrap Navbar as it is per default. Below each navigation item.

But I also want to scale the submenu background to the full width of the browser window.

I tried multiple solutions but couldn't find anything.

At the moment I try to use `:before` to set a background but that doesn't work either. Is there any solution for that?

Here's my code so far: https://codepen.io/cray_code/pen/QXNVLK

As you can see, there is a solution for the full-width dropdown. 
But I want the items below it's parent menu item and not on the left side.

This is the CSS for the full width version. There are no changes to the HTML of navbar itself:

```
.navbar-full .dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    right: 0 !important;
}

.navbar-full .dropdown, .navbar-full .navbar-nav .nav-item.dropdown {
    position: static !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you can do this using media queries, if you know your navbar menu items `@media only screen and (min-width: 768px)`.
2. You can also  reduce your code using bootstrap classes. Apply `w-100` for `dropdown-menu` and its parent `dropdown` should include class `position-static`
3. **Updated:** If you have no control over the menu items then you can achieve this by using jQuery

```
    $('a.nav-link').hover(function () {
      if ($(window).width() >= 768) {
        var myId = $(this).attr("id");
        if ($("#" + myId).length > 0) {
          var pos = Math.round($('#' + myId).position().left) + 12;
          $("a.dropdown-item").css('paddingLeft', pos + 'px');
        }
      }
    })
```

```js
$('a.nav-link').hover(function() {
  if ($(window).width() >= 768) {
    var myId = $(this).attr("id");
    if ($("#" + myId).length > 0) {
      var pos = Math.round($('#' + myId).position().left) + 12;
      $("a.dropdown-item").css('paddingLeft', pos + 'px');
    }
  }
})
```

```css
li.dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-full navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown position-static" id="parent">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown 1
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu w-100" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item mx-auto" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown position-static" id="parent1">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown1" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown 2
            </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu w-100" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown1">
            <a class="dropdown-item mx-auto" href="#">Hello</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">New</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I already have a solution for the full width dropdown. But I want the submenu placed under it's parent menu item

Comment: when you see you code in mobile view the sub-menu will not be under it's parent

Comment: But I want it to be under it's parent (in desktop view)

Comment: @Cray Check it now. Updated the snippet. please do let me know if it works for you.

Comment: It doesn't work if I add more links to the navbar because the padding is fix.

Comment: You need to adjust the padding accordingly. This does the work if you know the number of links you are having in the navbar

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control over the menu items

Comment: @Cray I have updated the above snippet using `jQuery` . Have a look. It works as per your requirement

Comment: Thanks, I will check it

Comment: @Cray Please feel free to up vote and accept my answer if it helps you. Thanks.

Comment: I'm opening the submenu by hover. Could you explain how to change you're code to function on hover? I tried `mouseover ` instead of `click` but that doesn't seem to work

Comment: Check the updated snippet for hover. Use `hover` instead of `click` .  Hope I have clearly answered your questions.

Comment: thanks, it works fine in your answer but on my site the style is not added to the link and I don't get why...

Comment: Check by copying and pasting my code. Please upvote & accept my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195073/discussion-between-sai-manoj-and-cray).